# Comparison between DATE field and DATETIME field with CASE conditions has slight errors in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following SQL query:

```
 SELECT e.num_employee AS num_employee,MIN(start_event) AS start_event,end_event, 
           CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DATE_FORMAT(start_event, '%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(entry) SECOND, start_event) > 15
                AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DATE_FORMAT(start_event, '%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(entry) SECOND, start_event) <= 40
                THEN 'MINOR DELAY' 
                WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DATE_FORMAT(start_event, '%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(entry) SECOND, start_event) > 40
                AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DATE_FORMAT(start_event, '%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(entry) SECOND, start_event) <= 90
                THEN 'MAJOR DELAY'
                ELSE 'CHECKED' END AS title
FROM events AS e 
    JOIN employees AS em ON e.num_employee= em.num_employee
    WHERE e.num_employee= $num_employee AND title = 'CHECKED'
    GROUP BY num_employee, DATE(start_event)
```

I use this query making reference to a table called "events" that contains the column "no_employee" that contains the identification number of each employee, "start_event" of type DATETIME that contains the date and time of a record and "title" of type VARCHAR that contains the title of said event/record. This table records the entries and exits of employees at their workplace.

At the same time, reference is made to the table "employees" that contains a column "not_employee" with its respective identifier number and "entry" of type TIME that contains the hour of entry of said person.

The rules are simple: if the employee has a record before his entry time and up to 15 minutes after it, it is considered "CHECKED" (which contains the "title" field by default); if the employee has a registration after 15 minutes of his entry time and before or equal to 40 minutes after his entry time, it is considered "MINOR DELAY"; and if the employee has a registration after 40 minutes of his entry time and up to 90 minutes later, it is considered "MAJOR DELAY".

The query works for the vast majority of my records, but I've caught a few exceptions where conditions are misapplied. For example, I have a record where start_event is "2022-11-17 07:14:00" of type DATETIME and input is "07:00:00" of type TIME , so it should be displayed in the "title" column as "CHECKED", but instead of being displayed that way, it is displayed as "MAJOR DELAY". Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

consider comparing the time portion of the start_event with the entry time without involving the date. Here's an updated version of your query that addresses this issue:

```sql
SELECT
    e.num_employee AS num_employee,
    MIN(start_event) AS start_event,
    end_event,
    CASE
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TIME(start_event), entry) > 15 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TIME(start_event), entry) <= 40 THEN 'MINOR DELAY'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TIME(start_event), entry) > 40 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TIME(start_event), entry) <= 90 THEN 'MAJOR DELAY'
        ELSE 'CHECKED'
    END AS title
FROM
    events AS e
    JOIN employees AS em ON e.num_employee = em.num_employee
WHERE
    e.num_employee = $num_employee
    AND title = 'CHECKED'
GROUP BY
    num_employee,
    DATE(start_event)
```

In this updated query, I have used the TIME() function to extract the time portion from the start_event column and directly compared it with the entry time. This ensures that the comparison is done accurately without considering the date portion.

By making this change, the query should correctly categorize the events based on the defined rules, including the case where the start_event time falls within the acceptable range of 15 minutes after the entry time.